# Using excel function in created VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a function in VBA, that I can then use in excel...

This is not the exact function that I want to create, but I'm having a lot of trouble so I simplified it down a lot...

Suppose I have the following matrix in my excel spreadsheet.

[image]

I know there is a built-in function in excel to find the determinate. Now, I want to use that in my function I define in VBA. Again there will be more stuff in my function, but I'm just trying to understand what I'm doing wrong.

So suppose this is my function I've defined in VBA...

```
Option Explicit

Public Function determinate(mtx As Range)

determinate = Application.MDeterm(mtx)

End Function
```

However, when trying to use determinate() in excel it doesn't calculate. Why is this/How can I fix this?

Comment: did you put the function to a Module or in the Sheet VBA part?

Comment: In a module....

Comment: Works for me - what error do you get?

Comment: I get #NAME? when I try using the function on the Sheet in excel.

Comment: what is your selection range? rows count must equal column count in the selection

Comment: Do you definitely have it in a standard module (not a class) and in the same workbook as the range?

Comment: For the selection range.. just the range of the matrix

Comment: Yes, it's just in a standard module in the same workbook.

Comment: #name looks like a typo in your function call on sheet (?)

Comment: @user6259845 how exactly do you use the function in your formula? It should be like `=determinate(A1:B2)`

Comment: what happens if you try this in the Immediate window? ?determinate(range("A1:D4"))

Comment: I typed it like =determinate(A1:B2) and it doesn't work.... but I just tried changing the name of my function in the VBA code to something else like "test" and it is now working. But it still doesn't work it I try it with the original function name I had. Does anyone know what would cause this?

Comment: If I renamed my module "determinate" would this cause the error?

Comment: Yes: module name should not match function name

Comment: Ah, that fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user6259845 Try to avoid duplicate names anyway, this can confuse humans too ;)

Comment: It would work if you used =determinate.determinate(A1:D4)

Comment: That's good to know, thank you again all for the advice/help.